# Disable autorotate while animation show

Tags: ios, objective-c, autorotate

Can I disable autorotation if my views animated in this moment? And then if orientation changed, after end of animation - change orientation manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting a flag when animation begins and based on that flag return NO from orientation delegates and once animation is completed reset the flag.